# Need help to convert Pinescript v2 to version 5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I found this code by chart art. I am building my own strategy and I would love this feature in mine. It provides better confirmation for my entry signals. Im trying to learn pinescript myself but I think it would take a lot of time and effort if I learn pinescript v2 and v5, so I am asking some help to convert this to V5 then I can continue improve the code. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you all in advance.

```
//@version=2

threshold = input(title="Price Difference Threshold", type=float, defval=0, step=0.001)

getDiff() =>
    yesterday=security(tickerid, 'D', close[1])
    today=security(tickerid, 'D', close)
    delta=today-yesterday
    percentage=delta/yesterday
    
closeDiff = getDiff()
 
buying = closeDiff > threshold ? true : closeDiff < -threshold ? false : buying[1]

hline(0, title="zero line")

bgcolor(buying ? #3399FF : #FFFFFF , transp=1)
plot(closeDiff, color=silver, style=area, transp=75)
plot(closeDiff, color=aqua, title="prediction")

longCondition = buying
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    
shortCondition = buying != true
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct v2 -> v5 conversion would look like this:

```
//@version=5
strategy("")
threshold = input.float(title="Price Difference Threshold", defval=0, step=0.001)

getDiff() =>
    yesterday=request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
    today=request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
    delta=today-yesterday
    percentage=delta/yesterday
    
closeDiff = getDiff()

bool buying = na 
buying := closeDiff > threshold ? true : closeDiff < -threshold ? false : buying[1]

hline(0, title="zero line")

bgcolor(buying ? #3399FF : #FFFFFF , transp=1)
plot(closeDiff, color=color.new(color.silver, 75), style=plot.style_area)
plot(closeDiff, color=color.aqua, title="prediction")

longCondition = buying
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    
shortCondition = buying != true
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

Note that the script uses the `security()` function to request data from the `"D"` timeframe, which allows it to look ahead into the future and get values of bars before it would be possible to do so on real-time charts ([more info here](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000614705)). This is frowned upon in new scripts. To avoid this, `barmerge.loohakead_off` should be used (it is turned on by default in v3 - v5). In the script below, I changed it, so the results will differ from the original script, but it is for the best, because the original script operates data that it should not be able to access:

```
//@version=5
strategy("")
threshold = input.float(title="Price Difference Threshold", defval=0, step=0.001)

getDiff() =>
    [today, yesterday] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', [close, close[1]], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)
    delta = today - yesterday
    percentage = delta / yesterday
    
closeDiff = getDiff()

bool buying = na 
buying := closeDiff > threshold ? true : closeDiff < -threshold ? false : buying[1]

hline(0, title="zero line")

bgcolor(buying ? color.new(#3399FF, 1) : color.new(#FFFFFF, 1))
plot(closeDiff, color=color.new(color.silver, 75), style=plot.style_area)
plot(closeDiff, color=color.aqua, title="prediction")

longCondition = buying
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    
shortCondition = buying != true
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```